# Why does iOS 9 have different glyphs for some characters on keyboard vs. on screen?

Tags: keyboard, font, ios

With the new San Francisco font in iOS 9 (honestly, I had never paid attention to this in previous versions), I notice that, for some characters, the glyph that actually gets put on the screen after pressing the corresponding key on the keyboard is different from the glyph on the keyboard itself.

This happens, for example, with the apostrophe, as you can see from this screenshot.

[image]

Does this happen for a reason?

Comment: Have you sent feedback to Apple? [apple.com/feedback](http://apple.com/feedback)

Comment: Are you sure that the font used for keyboard visualization and the one used in the Notes app is indeed the same font?

Comment: There is no necessary connection between the exact form of the keyboard character and what you see in an app.  The keyboard uses the system font, apps can normally use all kinds of different fonts.

Comment: But two different fonts, especially the keyboard and Notes ones, should have the same amount of characters and therefore display them quite similarly...

Comment: I assumed that apple own apps used system font (I posted a screenshot from Notes, but the same thing happens in Messages, etc.) and, as far as I can tell, the other characters seem to be using the system font.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has existed an every version of iOS until 10 as far as I know, and best I can figure is intentional since it probably would have been fixed by now. It's just more visible with San Francisco.

I don't know why Apple does it. Could it be that it looks better on the keyboard?

iOS 11 no longer has this behavior as it has added "smart quotes" à la Microsoft Word. Most of the time, as a result, you you will see the character you expected to see typed.

Comment: To avoid having your sms limit cut to 70, you need to turn off this smart punctuation feature, which is on by default for some users.